# keeps getting "Illegal arguments: undefined, string at Object.bcrypt.hashSync"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I've been struggling with Bcrypt on my MERN project I'm trying to create an authentication system I'm trying to run tests on Postman and I'm not sure why do I keep getting the error: "Illegal arguments: undefined, string at Object.bcrypt.hashSync"

this is my postman request:
[image]

this is the Controller Code:

```
const config = require("../config/auth.config");
const db = require("../models");
const User = db.user;
const Role = db.role;

var jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
var bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");

exports.signup = (req, res) => {
 const user = new User({
  username: req.body.username,
  email: req.body.email,
  password: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 8),
});

user.save((err, user) => {
if (err) {
  res.status(500).send({ message: err });
  return;
}

if (req.body.roles) {
  Role.find(
    {
      name: { $in: req.body.roles },
    },
    (err, roles) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send({ message: err });
        return;
      }

      user.roles = roles.map((role) => role._id);
      user.save((err) => {
        if (err) {
          res.status(500).send({ message: err });
          return;
        }

        res.send({ message: "User was registered successfully!" });
      });
    }
  );
} else {
  Role.findOne({ name: "user" }, (err, role) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send({ message: err });
      return;
    }

    user.roles = [role._id];
    user.save((err) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send({ message: err });
        return;
      }

      res.send({ message: "User was registered successfully!" });
     });
   });
  }
 });
};

exports.signin = (req, res) => {
  User.findOne({
   username: req.body.username,
  })
.populate("roles", "-__v")
.exec((err, user) => {
  if (err) {
    res.status(500).send({ message: err });
    return;
  }

  if (!user) {
    return res.status(404).send({ message: "User Not found." });
  }

  var passwordIsValid = bcrypt.compareSync(
    req.body.password,
    user.password
  );

  if (!passwordIsValid) {
    return res.status(401).send({ message: "Invalid Password!" });
  }

  var token = jwt.sign({ id: user.id }, config.secret, {
    expiresIn: 86400, // 24 hours
  });

  var authorities = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < user.roles.length; i++) {
    authorities.push("ROLE_" + user.roles[i].name.toUpperCase());
  }

  req.session.token = token;

  res.status(200).send({
    id: user._id,
    username: user.username,
    email: user.email,
    roles: authorities,
  });
 });
};

exports.signout = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    req.session = null;
  return res.status(200).send({ message: "You've been signed out!" });
 } catch (err) {
 this.next(err);
 }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message:
`Illegal arguments: undefined, string at Object.bcrypt.hashSync` wants to say that you're passing `undefined` as an argument to the `hashSync` function. We need to fix this error.

Take a closer look at this line where the error occurs:

`password: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 8),`

`req.body.password` is `undefined`, you can verify it by `console.log(req.body.password)`. What's wrong is that you are sending data as URL parameters. So `req.body` is an empty object and `req.body.password` is `undefined`.

In Postman, select the `Body` tab, choose JSON format, then type your data as a JSON object. Then, in your code, use `express.json()` middleware to parse requests in JSON format. You'll have the desired output.

You can see my example request in Postman below:
[image]

Comment: i tried it using JSON i kept getting the exact same error for some reason